# Maximize trace of precision matrix

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, hypercube

Let Q be the uniform distribution over the hypercube $\{1, -1\}^{d}$.
Let P be any distribution that has support including the hypercube.

Define $\Sigma=\mathbb{E}_{x \sim P}[x x^\top]$.

We'd like to maximize $\mathsf{trace}(\Sigma^{-1})$ under the constraint
that $\sum_{v \in {\{1, -1\}^{d}}} \frac{q_v^2}{p_v} \leq \lambda$,
where $q_v$ and $p_v$ are the probability mass function of $Q$ and $P$, respectively.

Note that $q_v$ is identically $1 / (2^d)$ and the possible ranges for $\lambda$ is $[1,+\infty)$.

What's the optimal value and optimal solution to this problem?